# segfault with clone() and printf

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, system-calls

I'm trying to experiment with how `clone()` is implemented for threads in Linux 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64

I'm running this piece of code and having occasional segfaults. I know if I use `CLONE_THREAD` then there's no way to check if the thread finished, but why does `printf` cause problems? How does the `Pthread` library handle this issue? Without the `printf`s there's no segfault.

```
#define STACK_SIZE (1ULL<<22) //4MB

int tmp = 10;

int threadfunc(void *ptr)
{
    printf("i'm here\n");
    tmp++;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char *child_stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    int child_pid = clone(&threadfunc, child_stack+(STACK_SIZE)-1, CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|SIGCHLD, NULL);

    printf("my pid: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("child pid: %d\n", child_pid);
    printf("tmp is: %d\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's tricky to use `clone()` correctly.  99% of the time you want either `fork()` or `pthread_create()` instead.

Comment: ...just made this comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58731945/what-did-printf-do-in-the-shared-memory
... the default stdio buffer size is 8192 bytes in my machine ... i had been making a stack less than 4096 ok before i started using printf ... unbuffering it at first had opposite effect that wanted, so then i setvbuf with buffer i allocated of 256 bytes with line buffering ( setvbuf ( stdout , buffer , _IOLBF , 128 ) ) and then all was ok with a small stack for each CLONE_VM and short printf lines ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `printf` function doesn't understand that it's being called in a `clone` 
task; it is designed around the glibc pthread library.

What you're doing is similar to interrupting a `printf` with an asynchronous signal, and re-entering `printf` from the signal.

How the library handles the issue is that it uses `clone` as part of a more complicated implementation of threads, which "dresses up" the cloned task with a thread identity. This thread identity allows `printf` to lock a mutex around the stream operation.

What is the thread identity? What it means is that a thread-related function in the C library can inquire, in some way, "what thread is calling me?" to obtain an ID, which maps to a thread descriptor structure. The `clone` function alone won't set up this identity.